Meaning of Śrī Madhurakālikāmbā Suprabhātam
Could anyone kindly provide the meaning of this song?
https://www.ranjanigayatri.com/srimadhurakaliammansuprabhatam
Śrī Madhurakālikāmbā Suprabhātam
।। Om Namaḥ Śrī Dakṣiṇakālikāyai ।।
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbikāmba siruvaccūr ramyadevālaye
bhaktānugrahakāraṇāya satataṁ siṁhādhirūḍhe pare |
bhaktānāṁ smaraṇena tuṣṭahṛdaye sarvāpadāṁ nāśinī
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike suvidite te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
śrīmacChaṁkaraśaṅkarāryabhagavatpādaiḥ susampūjite
tanmantraiśca sumantritākhilajanakṣemaprade yantrake |
rājantī sakaleṣṭamāśu tanuṣe māteva vātsalyataḥ
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike sulalite te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
tvaṁ haimādrisamudbhavāpi ca punaḥ vindhyādrivāsā mudā
śrīmaddakṣiṇakāliketi siruvāccūr naijaramyālaye |
bhaktābhīṣṭaphalaprade ca namatāṁ sarvārtisaṁhāriṇī
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike bhayahare te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
aṣṭabhiśca karaiḥ sahetisubhagaiḥ śatrukṣaye dīkṣite
bhaktānugrahaṇe varābhayakarau vīrāsanaṁ cāśrite |
jvālāmālikayā pradīptamatulaṁ śūlaṁ kare bibhratī
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike sumahite te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
koṇānāṁ tritayena ramyasumahāyantrālaye dīvyase
śaktīnāṁ navabhiḥ sukoṇasugataiḥ dikpālakaiḥ saṁvṛte |
svīyaiḥ mantravaraiḥ sumantritamahāyantrālaye dīpyase
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike atimadhure te suprabhātaṁ śivam||
lokānāṁ hitakāmyayā karuṇayā śrīkāli hatvā ripūn
nānārūpadharaṁ mahogramahiṣaṁ śumbhaṁ niśumbhaṁ tathā |
raktākṣaṁ śaṭharaktajihvamaparaṁ caṇḍaṁ ca muṇḍaṁ kṣaṇāt
cāmuṇḍā śrīmadhurāmbike vijayase te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
tvaṁ bhītān ditijān savāsavamukhān devān hi saṁrakṣituṁ
śaktīnāṁ ca gaṇaiḥ sahaiva samare tān cāvadhīḥ daityakān |
bhūyaścāpi bhaye sadaiva manujān rakṣāmi rakṣāmi ceti
ānandāt tvamasāntvayaḥ kila śive te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
vāyurvāti suśītalaḥ sukhakaraḥ śāntaṁ nabho vartate
pūṣodeti phalanti caiva taravaḥ puṣyanti mallyādayaḥ |
udbudhyasva śive kaṭākṣaya janān bhaktān hi rakṣekṣaṇe
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike sahṛdaye te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
sarve bhaktajanāḥ sadāraśiśukāḥ sannārikelaṁ phalaṁ
tāmbūlaṁ kamalaṁ sugandhi ca navaṁ gavyaṁ ca gandhaṁ kare |
dhṛtvā tvāṁ pratipālayanti jagatāṁ śrīmātaraṁ kālikāṁ
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike sulalite te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
tārānāyakaśobhiratnamakuṭe tāpiñchavarṇojvale
tārtīyīkavilocanāgnimahite tāṁbūlapūrṇānane |
mādhvīkādimahābhiṣekamudite mālāvibhūṣojvale
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike śubhakare te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
vyādāyaiva viśālamāsyaṁ acirāt bhitvā ripoḥ cāpyuraḥ
pītvā śoṇitamāśuraktavadane raktekṣaṇe jihvike |
tārtīyīkavilocanena ditijān yā bhasmasaccākaroḥ
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike vidhinute te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
dṛṣṭvā vīryam acintyaṁ adbhutatamaṁ vismāpanīyaṁ sadā
brahmā-viṣṇu-maheśvarādimasūrāḥ yāṁ tuṣṭuvuḥ śrīsumaiḥ |
sā tvaṁ viśvajanīnavandyavibhave haiyaṅgavīnāśaye
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike'tisulabhe te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
dvāviṁśanmanubhiḥ sadā sumahite śrībhadrakālīśvari
durgā-lakṣmi-sarasvatītyabhidhayā vikhyātacaṇḍīśvari |
śūlodbhāsikarāmbuje natajane sarvasvadānodyate
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike susubhage te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
some bhārgavavāsare'pi sujanaiḥ nānādigantāgataiḥ
tailābhyaktaśirobhireva satataṁ saṁsevitāṅghridvaye |
mātṛṇāṁ ca susaptabhiśca navabhiḥ durgādibhiḥ saṁvṛte
mātaḥ maṅgalakāriṇīṣṭavarade te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
tvaṁ bālā tripurā parā sulalitā pratyaṅgirāḥ śāradā
vācāmīśvari caṇḍikā ca bhagalā jvālāmukhī vaiṣṇavī |
lakṣmīrnīlasarasvatī ca vijayā-śākambharī cānnadā
sarvāḥ tvaṁ madhurāmbike vijayase te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
kāmanāmatha pūraṇaikasuvidhau tvaṁ kāmadhenuḥ śubhe
bhaktaiḥ cintita sarvadāna suvidhau cintāmaṇiḥ tvaṁ hi naḥ |
kāṅkṣāpūraṇa cāturī sumahitaḥ śrīkalpavṛkṣaḥ svayaṁ
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike iṣṭavarade te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
sarvāścaryamayaikacitracarite vismāpanīyo'dya me
viśvārātivināśanaikanipuṇe vidyāvayovardhini |
vedāntapratipādyamānavibhave viśvaikajīvātuke
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike bhayahare te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
saumaṅgalya-subhartṛputrasukhade sauvāsinīpūjite
saundaryaikanidhe surendravinute saubhāgyasaṁvardhini|
sauśīlyādiguṇaprade ca namatāṁ satsaumanasyaprade
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike śrutinute te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
vīṇā-veṇu-mṛdaṅga-nāṭayamudite vīṇāmunīndrastute
śrīdurgāparasūktamantrasulabhe vāṇī-ramā-vījite |
durgā-lakṣmi-sarasvatīti vinute kāmeśavāmāṅgake
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike sulalite te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
dīpaṁ dīpayatīha yacca samaye śrīsomavāre punaḥ
tat sukrāvadhi jājvalatyatitarāṁ caitanmahatvaṁ tava |
talliptaṁ ca sucandanaṁ sukusumaṁ yaccārcitaṁ pādayoḥ
naiva glāmyati sarvaśaktibharite te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
saṁprāptāstava sannidhiṁ hi kṛpayā saṁprāpnuvanti dhruvaṁ
cetohāri susundaraṁ nijapatiṁ vidyāvayobhāsvaram |
saumaṅgalyasamṛddhiṁ āśu lalanāḥ vidyāṁ ca bālāḥ dhanaṁ
sarvatraiva jayaṁ sadā sumadhure te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
kiṁ vā duṣkaramambike tava padadvandvaikasaktātmanām
kiṁ vā durlabhamasti tāvakamanuṁ japtuḥ sadā dhyāyinām |
kiṁ vā durjayamasti raktakusumaiḥ nityārcanāṁ kurvatām
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike iṣṭavarade te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
dātrī tvaṁ nikhilāni caihikasukhānyātṛpti vandaruke
dāsyantī sakalaṁ manorathaphalaṁ cāmuṣmikaṁ dehinām |
sālokyādi catuṣṭayaṁ ca sahasā datvā'nugṛhṇāsi naḥ
mataḥ śrīmadhurāmbike iṣṭavarade te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
sūryācandramasau tathā kujabudhau jīvaśca śukraḥ śaniḥ
rāhuḥ keturabhīṣṭanityavaradāḥ yogāśca tārāgaṇāḥ |
śrīkālīcaraṇāravindapatitaṁ no pīḍayanti dhruvaṁ
śrīniḥśreyasadāyike sumadhure te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
sarveṣāṁ ca manaḥ praśāntimadhunā datvā'nugṛhṇīṣva naḥ
māyāmohitajantujātamadhunā vijñānapūrṇaṁ kuru |
sarvatraiva cakāstu bhāratatale śāntiḥ praśāntiḥ sukhaṁ
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike suvarade te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
jvālāmālini caṇḍike sumadhure sāndrāntaraṅge sadā
ajñānāt kṛtamantujālamadhunā tvaṁ vai kṣamasvāmbike |
nāvā sindhumivādya tāraya janaṁ saṁsāravāraṁnidheḥ
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike sakaruṇe te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
saṁrājñīpura-siruvāccūrvāsinī bhagavatī śrīmādhurī kālikā
suprātaḥ prapaṭhet uṣasyapi mudā yo vā naraḥ pratyaham |
taṁ vai rakṣati sāndranaijahṛdayā māteva vātsalyataḥ
mātaḥ śrīmadhurāmbike sulalite te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
devī tvāṁ śaraṇaṁ gato'smi satataṁ nānyā gatistvāṁ vinā
tvaṁ mātāsi pitā tathaiva sahajaḥ bandhuśca putrī sutaḥ |
sarvasvaṁ hi mama tvameva siruvāccūr rājñi rakṣekṣaṇe
pāhyasmān sakuṭumbakān sumadhure te suprabhātaṁ śivam ||
saptaviṁśatisaṁkhyāka-suprātakamalaiḥ subhaiḥ |
tvāmarcayāmi madhure prasīda varadā bhava ||
